# What do I return for an empty list on a question about functions?

Tags: haskell

This is the exercise in question

Define the function
`compose :: [a → a] → (a → a)`, which composes a list of functions
into a single function, so, for example:
`compose [f0,f1,f2] x = f0 (f1 (f2 x))`

What I have coded up looks like this

```
compose :: [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
compose (f:fs) = f . (compose fs)
```

Now I need something to return for if the argument [a -> a] is empty, but I don't know what. So for case `compose []`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has already been answered, but some generic base case advice follows. It is often the case that the operation you are using to combine your list has an identity associated with it, and then that identity is usually a good choice. Examples: `(+)` has identity `0`, and `sum [] = 0`; `(*)` has identity `1`, and `product [] = 1`; `(&&)` has identity `True`, and `and [] = True`; etc. Failing that, it can be instructive to think about how you want the one-element list case to behave. What should `compose [f]` do? What does `compose []` need to be for that to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `id`, it will map the element on itself. This would also be the neutral element in a monoid you can build over functions:

```
compose :: [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
compose [] = id
compose (f : fs) = f . (compose fs)
```

your function is equivalent to:

```
compose :: Foldable f => f (a -> a) -> a -> a
compose = foldr (.) id
```